# Composer update error: Installing smatar/laravel-settings (1.3): Downloading (failed). Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git, laravel-5, permissions

I'm having this error when I execute composer update in my laravel project (it's been working for years):

```
 - Installing smatar/laravel-settings (1.3): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download smatar/laravel-settings from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/SMATAR/laravel-settings/zipball/7b76462fe90224688c632d90c5f84a28c0f6e2bc" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing smatar/laravel-settings (1.3): The authenticity of host 'github.com (18.231.5.6)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Cloning 7b76462fe9


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/SMATAR/laravel-settings.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/SMATAR/laravel-settings.git
    Cloning into '/var/www/html/prod/web/vendor/smatar/laravel-settings'...
    remote: Invalid username or password.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/SMATAR/laravel-settings.git/'
  - git@github.com:SMATAR/laravel-settings.git
    Cloning into '/var/www/html/prod/web/vendor/smatar/laravel-settings'...
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '18.228.67.229' to the list of known hosts.
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Package deleted from github: https://github.com/SMATAR/laravel-settings

Packagist page for package: https://packagist.org/packages/smatar/laravel-settings

You must contact with package publisher.

Comment: Sorry, so, if someone deletes a package then my project dies?  What's the best practice for external packages? Should I include those in my repository (SVN) ? I don't want to depend on other people just deleting a package and then my project not working anymore. So, what's usually done about this.

Comment: You can fork original package  on github  and publish on packagist with your user namespace. And you can depend your application packages from your packagist repository. When updates come from original package, you can pull changes and update your packages. This approach may be duplicate packages but it keeps alive. Or you can keep `vendor` folder in secure place and you don't update packages.

Comment: Can I still use the packagist content and recreate a github repository to fix my project?

Comment: Packagist is only bridge for repositories. It does not contain source code of packages. They standing on github. You should access github repository for `laravel-settings` package. You said `it's been working for years`. Did you have this package?

Comment: I don't have the source code. Should I have downloaded and stored it? I probably have it inside an autmoatic backup (from a production server)...

Comment: Yes you must store. Also create package on packagist for production dependency.

Comment: where can I read more about this? I'm not sure what you mean when you say I should create package on packagist, etc. THanks

Comment: You can read packagist about page. https://packagist.org/about and composer documentation. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md